# Does Adding a Primary Key to a table checks default columns?

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I tried to add primary key in a table and set it as a column that has default value and is not null and is not unique.MySQL accepted that column as Primary Key...I want to know that this is wrong as if a user enters 2 records having default values he will not be able to do so..Is this a problem where SQL should have checked column as non default values or this is a designer end problem that default columns should not be made Primary Key...?

Comment: A `primary key` means that all the values should be `unique` and `not null`.

Comment: Furthermore, the `primary key` should identify unambiguously every record in the table.

Comment: if User adds a Primary key as a column with default value...should SQL prompt it as a error or not?

Comment: No. The error should appear only when you try to insert duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Null:

every column that is flagged wiht NULL is just specified that this column may contain a NULL value. The column can still have another default value.

Primary key:

- A PK is always treated unique and you cannot have two identical values on a row
- There can only be one PK per table, its the main index which is very fast when querying the table on its primary column.
- A PK is always a single column and cannot be spread over multiple columns as every other index (unique or usual index) can do.
- A PK column cannot accept NULL values

Sample:

```
ID (INT, PK) |  Name (varchar)
 1           |   Foo            ->Valid
 2           |   Bar            ->Valid
 2           |   FooBar         ->Invalid (Duplicate Primary key value ID)
```

Conclusion: Yes MySQL should and will throw an error at second attempt to put a default value because its simply treated UNIQUE and a given default value is const. The MySQL server will attempt to insert the default value when you dont specify any value for this column in your insert statement.

Pretty much means: A PrimaryKey column with a default value makes no sense, except you use an auto-increment which is a pseudo "default value" which is different each time you try to insert something.

I hope this answers your questions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding the problem.  You have declared a column to be a primary key that has these characteristics:

- NOT NULL
- Default value

A primary key imposes these characteristics:

- NOT NULL
- Unique

These characteristics are not mutually incompatible.  The only issue is that the default value can only be assigned once in the column.  The second time you try to insert a row with the default value, you will get a violation of the uniqueness constraint.

In other words, MySQL (and I think other databases as well) allow you declare this even if it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: i tried to replicate more and found that if only one default column record is present then SQL will not show error and accept that column as updated Primary Key....but if multiple records are present SQL WILL Prompt error like for any other constraint violation

Comment: @AmanVerma . . . That is the correct behavior for this type of declaration.